# Sddm theme works in test mode but not when logging in

Tags: linux, fedora, sddm

I'm running Fedora 36 on both my laptop (specs: ryzen 5900hs and rtx 3060) and my desktop (specs: ryzen 6 3600 and rtx 2070S). I installed and enabled sddm, and applied [this theme](https://store.kde.org/s/KDE%20Store/p/1312658). Same process and config file for both devices, but for some reason on laptop it is correct but not on my desktop. Even though on desktop, it shows correctly when running the greeter in test mode using: `sddm‑greeter ‑‑test‑mode ‑‑theme /usr/share/sddm/themes/sugar‑candy` but when booting it is shown incorrectly.

What I'm supposed to see, aka what I see in test mode and laptop
[image: What I'm supposed to see, aka what I see in test mode and laptop]

What I actually see when booting PC
[image: What I actually see when booting PC]